# Adding UIViewController subclass with IBOutlet

Tags: iphone

I have seen this example on Apple's website before, but for some reason, I cannot find it and am brainfarting.  I created a TestViewController.h and .m file that subclass from UIViewController and have a .xib.  In the TestAppDelegate.h, I have:

```
@interface TestAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

    TestViewController *rootController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet TestViewController *rootController;
```

in TestAppDelegate.m, I have:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window addSubview:rootController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Then in my MainWindow.xib, I drag a ViewController, change the class to TestViewController, control drag the outlet from TestAppDelegate to TestViewController.  It builds fine, but when I run it I get:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<TestViewController 0x4d06570> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key label.'
```

I cannot remember what I'm missing in these steps.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Check the class again in the nib to see if the class is TestViewController in the attributes inspector..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@interface TestAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

TestViewController *rootController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet TestViewController *rootController;
```

in TestAppDelegate.m, I have:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.
[self.window addSubview:rootController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

IF IT IS THE CODE YOU ARE REALLY USING THEN ADD FOLLOWING LINE TO YOUR INTERFACE:

```
UIWindow *window;
```

AND CHECK IF IT HELPS.

Answer (score 0):

For your window you need to setup you rootViewController. By the way your naming "rootController" is kind of misleading, b/c UIWindow has a property rootViewController.
So to get this to work instead line `[self.window addSubview:rootController.view];` you should do this `self.window.rootViewController = self.rootController;`

If you want to compare your code with a working code just create new project from template. Choose View-Based Application it has the schema you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Open the TestViewController.xib and check whether any false outlets are connected there. Select the FilesOwner and go to connection inspector. The false outlets will be shown faded.. In this case, it would be label

Answer (score 0):

Check your outlets in Interface Builder, you have something named "label" that does not exist. Remove the reference to this and you should be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

again checkout....

use the connection inspector and write nib name and class name....in main View Controller.Xib